# How do I get active contracts?

Tags: team-fortress-2

My contracts won't work. It always says "There is no campaign active campaign.  Contracts are unavailable". Every day I check my contracts and I never get one.

Comment: At this point and time there are no active campaigns for you to complete contracts.  It is speculated that the next major update (the Pyro update not the smissmas update we just had) will bring a return to campaigns,  which will give you active contracts.

Answer (score 3):

Contracts are part of the limited time campaigns such as [Gun Mettle Campaign](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Gun_Mettle_Campaign#Notes) or [Scream Fortress 2015](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scream_Fortress_2015). Joining a campaign may require an item, such as Gun Mettle Campaign Pass, to enter. Per the [FAQ](http://www.teamfortress.com/gunmettle/faq/) you are not able to do contracts when the campaign is over.